# How to specify properties of wx.MouseEvent?

Tags: unit-testing, wxpython

I am trying to write a PyUnit unit test for one of my wxPython classes, which receives mouse wheel events. The unit test spawns a mouse event with

```
event = wx.MouseEvent(mouseType=wx.wxEVT_MOUSEWHEEL)
```

Unfortunately, it spawns a mouse wheel event with `WheelRotation = 0`. The `MouseEvent` class prevents me from manually setting a nonzero wheel rotation which in turn prevents me from testing the nontrivial cases of my event handler.

Is there a way to synthetically generate mouse wheel events with nonzero rotations (which can be used in unit tests)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure it is a valid way to do this but:

```
>>> import wx
>>> event = wx.MouseEvent(mouseType=wx.wxEVT_MOUSEWHEEL)
>>> event.WheelRotation = 22
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> event.m_wheelRotation = 22
>>> event.WheelRotation
22                                                                             
>>> event.m_wheelRotation = 25
>>> event.WheelRotation                                                 
25                                                                             
>>>
```